# Why does the "w" command report a wrong number of logged in users?

Tags: linux, login, session, w

I have logged in from tty6, then logged out. Now, executing the `w` command from a terminal inside `unity` gives the following output:

```
mark@mark-Latitude-D620:~$ w
19:27:19 up  2:40,  3 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.61, 0.46
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mark     tty7                      16:47    2:39m  5:06   0.22s gnome-session -
mark     pts/2    :0.0             19:13    7.00s  0.30s  0.00s w
```

Isn't the command supposed to list only the logged in users? I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

**Edit**

Note that the `w` command reports that 3 users are logged in (in the header) but only shows 2 entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing surprising about this `w` output. If you look at the second column under the `TTY` heading, it says the two logins are from `tty7` (not `tty6`!) and `pts/2`. Now `tty7` is your graphical log in (see the `WHAT` column) and `pts/2` is a pseudo-terminal device which is the terminal emulator you opened to run the `w` command (again, see the `WHAT` column).

**Update**

It seems that the wrongly reported number of users can occur sometimes when your `/var/run/utmp`, which `w` makes use of, is corrupt.

The solution I found suggested on the Internet is to truncate this file (perhaps in single-user mode) and retry logging in:

```
# >/var/run/utmp
# reboot
```

Proceed with caution, though, it is suggested that users logged in while you nuke `/var/run/utmp` will experience "weirdness", which is why people recommend you do this in single-user mode.

**Sources**

- [w shows 2 users when there is only 1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/w-shows-2-users-when-there%27s-only-1-a-833203/)
- [Corrupt /var/run/utmp](http://www.mail-archive.com/redhat-list@redhat.com/msg02706.html)

Comment: it says 3 users

Comment: @user1298069 You're right, that _is_ weird. I tried but couldn't reproduce your issue (I logged in at `tty1` then logged back out): `w` produces the correct output in my case. What do you get with `last|head`?

Comment: I have just logged again from an other tty and now it says 4 users even that I have logged out

Comment: @user1298069 Can you please update the question with the output of `last|head`?

Comment: what is the exact command?

Comment: @user1298069 Never mind, please see the updated answer.