# w command doesn't show all pseudo-terminal sessions

Tags: login, session, xfce4-terminal, w, pts

If I open terminal and execute `w` command then it will show:

```
user   tty7     :0               12:04   39:56  36.87s  0.06s /sbin/upstart -
```

Now if open `terminator` or `xterm` and execute `w` command then it will show it's entry in the output of `w` command like

```
user   tty7     :0               12:04   39:56  36.87s  0.06s 
/sbin/upstart -
user   pts/2    :0.0             12:50    1.00s  0.02s  0.00s w
```

but it will not show a new entry when I open `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal`.
Why it is showing new session for terminator and not for xfce4-terminal?

Comment: Are those terminals running your shell as an _interactive login shell_ or just like an _interactive shell_ (see if `$-` contains an `l` in the shell).

Comment: what is `$-` . I am getting error `himBH command not found` and for `echo    $-` it says himBH

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92784/why-does-the-w-command-report-a-wrong-number-of-logged-in-users

Comment: I read it earlier but didn't get it.

Comment: Interesting question that attracted two excellent answers. I've edited the title so that others may find this more easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`w` displays the information stored in `utmp` (`/var/run/utmp` typically on Linux systems). This generally is only updated by “login” sessions, *i.e.* `login` (for logins on virtual consoles or serial connections), the display manager (for graphical sessions), the SSH server (for SSH connections), and some (most?) terminal emulators. In the latter case, whether or not they update `utmp` depends on their built-in support and configuration; for example `xterm` has the `ut` flag for this (`-ut` disables `utmp` updates, `+ut` enables them), and GNOME Terminal [no longer updates `utmp` directly at all](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046).

So you’re seeing the entries which have been added to `utmp` in your case: one added by your display manager (on `tty7`), and others added by some of the terminal emulators you’re using.

It should be possible to wrap commands to add `utmp` logging to anything you like, using for example `libutempter`, but that is apparently [not as straightforward as one might hope](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869617).

Comment: Is it possible to change the configuration of `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 2):

`w` does not show terminal sessions. The *login* database, that the `w` program reports on, is not a *terminal* database.  (Formally, it is a *user accounting* database, but the *Single Unix Specification* is incomplete on this point.)

If it were a terminal database, it would record all of the *pseudo* terminals that programs use, from the likes of NeoVIM, emacs, `tmux`, `screen`, `ptybandage`, `ptyrun`, and even `script`.  But it does not, and it is not.

(One can make a similar argument, that needs a slightly greater knowledge of history, about it not recording "call out" terminal usage and the likes of BBS, FidoNet, and UUCP terminal sessions.)

As a *login* database, it records *login sessions*, both textual and graphical.  The libvte people make the argument that writing to this database is within the purview of the *login* subsystems, graphical and textual, not within the purview of a terminal *emulator* that runs *within* login sessions.  This is a fair point, bolstered by the fact that it makes a nonsense of the security of login accounting to allow programs outwith the Trusted Computing Base to write/update the login database.

As such, you shouldn't expect every terminal emulator session to show up as a login session in the login database — or indeed *any* terminal emulator sessions.  Even terminal emulators that are invoking login shells *are not doing any actual logging on to the system*, and are acting entirely within an already-logged-in session.  Terminal emulator writers tried to make the login database record terminal emulator sessions, but the effort has led to a number of problems, long-since recognized.

Conversely, you *should* expect to see a single record for your *GUI* login session.  (Although, as explained in an article in further reading, in practice this is rather a mess.)

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437762/5132
- [`pututxline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pututxline.html).   *Base Specifications*.  IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. However, I don't really understand this part: "it makes a nonsense of the security of login accounting to allow programs *outwith* the Trusted Computing Base to write/update the login database."

Comment: It just occurred to me that *outwith* may have been intended as *outwit*.  Maybe, *undermine* might be a better word - but I'm not particularly familiar with the concept of Trusted Computing Base.